# user_data becomes nil in pjsua_im_send. How to fix?

Tags: ios, pjsip

I am using *pjsua* for voip ( Voice Over IP ) messaging in my ios app. Whilst sending messages, I want to pass user_data and need to read when the pjsip status response recieves data.
The code is as following,

```
const char *timestampstr = [dateString UTF8String];
pjsua_im_send(acc_id, &to, &mime_type, &text, &msg_data, &timestampstr);
```

But after receiving the response the **user_data** becomes **nil**. Especially whenever I am getting a **408** response.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line before sending text message.

`const char *timestampstr = [dateString UTF8String];
 pj_str_t text;
 text = pj_str((char*) timestampstr);
 status = pjsua_im_send(acc_id, &sendTo, NULL, &text, NULL, NULL);`

Comment: I don't want to send the timestamp as message. I want to pass the timestamp as user data. So that I can read the user data when I get the response from server.